# Как избавиться от дубликатов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

необходимо ['S', 'A', 'M'], а у меня ['S', 'S', 'A', 'A', 'M', 'M']

```
def intersect(*args):
    res = []
    for x in args[0]:
        if x in res:
            continue
        for other in args[1:]:
            if x not in other:
                break
            else:
                res.append(x)
    return res


print(intersect('SPAM', 'SCAM', 'SLAM'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В своем решении уменьшите отступ у 9 и 10 строки.  Или перепишите так:

```
def intersect(*args):
    res = []
    for x in args[0]:
        if x not in res:
            for other in args[1:]:
                if x not in other:
                    break
            else:
                res.append(x)
    return res

print(intersect('SSSSSSPAMMMM', 'SCAAAM', 'SSSSSLAM'))
```

Вывод:

```
['S', 'A', 'M']
```

[Демо](https://rextester.com/GVFAC7353).
Решение основано на использовании [`else` в циклах](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь разумно использовать принцип инварианта: пересечение всех элементов это пересечение первого и оставшихся и т.д.

Создадим функцию, которая находит пересечение двух строк.

```
def intersect(a,b):
    temp=[]
    for x in a:
        if (x in b):
            if not (x in temp):
                temp.append(x)
    return temp
```

Далее создадим функцию, которая находит пересечение нескольких строк

```
def intersectM(*args):
    temp=args[0]
    for x in args[1:]:
        temp=intersect(temp,x)
    return temp


print(intersectM('SSSSSSPPPPPPAAAAMMMMM', 'SSSSSCAM', 'SLAM'))
```

Вывод

```
['S', 'A', 'M']
```

Answer (score 0):

Превратить итоговый список в множество (сет):

```
print(set(intersect('SPAM', 'SCAM', 'SLAM')))
```

Если же нужен список, то сет нужно опять конвертировать в список:

```
print(list(set(intersect('SPAM', 'SCAM', 'SLAM'))))
```

Нужно помнить, что в общем случае порядок элементов не будет сохранен.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(dict.fromkeys(['S', 'S', 'A', 'A', 'M', 'M']))
```

---

```
myList = [...]
cleanlist = []
[cleanlist.append(x) for x in myList if x not in cleanlist]
```

---

[Тут же и другие варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)